# Excel VBA Validation List set Default Value

Tags: vba, list, excel, validation

I have worked out the following code (minus the Dim and Set section, but WS1 = Sheet1 and WS2 = Sheet2) that will set all 'Validation List' default values on my target Excel Worksheet to the first item in their referenced Tables:

```
'+++Work through the processing of the 'Validation Lists' in the Worksheet+++
For Each rngValList In WS1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Cells
    With rngValList
        If .Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
            'Process those that should be set as the first value in the list.
            .Value = Range(Replace(.Validation.Formula1, "=", "")).Cells(1, 1)
        End If
    End With
Next rngValList
```

However, there is one Validation List on that same target page where I would like to set the default value to a different item contained in the list. I can do this by just separately calculating the item and then updating the cell where the Validation List values are selected, which works. But, what I'd really like to do is have the list (which is long) focus on the targeted default item, when the drop-down button is selected. Using this method, the first item in the drop-down list is still the focus of the list.

I tried modifying the code above to change the default value (probably in a way too complex change, but it worked), and it does select the correct value. But, the focus in the drop-down list is still on the first item in the list, when it is selected.

My modified code is as follows:

```
    '+++Work through the processing of the 'Validation Lists' in the Worksheet+++
    For Each rngValList In WS1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Cells
        With rngValList
            If .Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
                'If the Valdation List is Month End, then select the correct month date.
                If .Validation.Formula1 = "=LUT_MonthEnd" Then
                    'Set the Default End Month value to the correct Month.
                    i = 0
                    For Each rngSMList In WS2.Range(TS).Cells
                        i = i + 1
                        With rngSMList
                            If rngSMList = WS2.Range(DS) Then
                                 'Capture the counter at this point and exit to the rngValList Range Object.
                                 GoTo EndMthStop
                            End If
                        End With
                    Next rngSMList
EndMthStop:
                    .Value = Range(Replace(.Validation.Formula1, "=", "")).Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    'Process those that should be set as the first value in the list.
                    .Value = Range(Replace(.Validation.Formula1, "=", "")).Cells(1, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End With
```

This is not a big deal, as I am able to set the default value to the correct one, so things work fine as it is. But, it would be nice to have the default value selected be the one in focus when the drop-down list is selected, rather than always the first item in the list.

Conceptually, I guess what I need is a pointer to the correct default value in the target Table List.

Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished would be most appreciated.

Regards,

Wayne

Comment: You could use the selection change event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-selectionchange-event-excel) along with the instersect method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel) to identify when the cell is selected, then set the cell value as required. The list will then open on that item.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. I'm still finding my way with Excel VBA, so I'm not familiar with that event and method. But I'll certainly take a look at them when I get the chance.

Comment: Ok Absinthe, I actually managed to try this out this evening and while the process is new to me and strikes me as an interesting and useful means of setting a default value while navigating around a Worksheet (setting the default when I clicked on the cell worked well for me), it still doesn't address my specific need. With the default value now correctly selected in the cell upon navigating to that cell, it is still doing what my current code does.

Comment: That is, when I click on the dropdown list, the first item in the list is still the one at the top of the list, not the one that I have now have selected as the default, which could be a long way down in my dropdown list. As I say, this would be an adjustment which would be a nice to have and is not a show stopper. But it is placing the focus of the dropdown list on the default item that I selected, which I'm after.

Comment: As a matter of fact, my current code works better, because it is purposefully triggered when the user selects my form [Reset] button. So, any suggestions on how to change the focus of the dropdown list to the newly selected default value is what I'm really after. Cheers, Wayne

Comment: Are you running your code with mine? Because mine definitely does what you asked for.

Comment: Yes. Exactly as you described, via the 'Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange' Event. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the 'A1' cell in your example, but I pointed that at the range that contains my dropdown list. The "Your Value" is set to the default value that I want to display. That works, but my list, when I click on the drop-down arrow still defaults to display from the beginning of the list, not from the default value. I'll tyr again, but so far it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, along with my comments above. Paste the following code into the worksheet object (not a module).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.value = "Your Value"
End If

End Sub
```

The `Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange`is an event that fires every time a new cell is selected.

`Application.Intersect` returns a range that represents the overlap between two ranges.

The example above assumes your list is in cell A1.

Target is the cell that was clicked on, so we set the value of the cell to whatever value you want selected in your list.

Comment: Hey thanks, Absinthe. I'll not be able to try this out until I get back to the office on Monday (unless I find a bit of time over the weekend), but I'll definitely give this a go. I never thought of leveraging an event trigger in the Worksheet Object. Much appreciated. Once I've had the chance to try this out, I'll report back on the outcome. Wayne

Answer (score 0):

select the cell in which you have put the listitem.

the range for the listitem is "Opleiding"

in your VBA code:

```
selection.Value = Range("opleiding").Cells(2, 1)
```

the result is that the selected item of the listItem is the second item in the range "Opleiding"